# Pasting a selected range from Excel to a Word document

Tags: excel, vb.net, vsto

I am converting code I had written in Excel VBA to vb.NET on VS 2017. When I run the code, I get the error

> This method or property is not available because the Clipboard is
>   empty or not valid.

This message appears while the application is running, when it tries to paste the selected range from Excel to the Word document. I have kept the worksheet being copied visible while the code runs, and can see that it selects the correct range but doesn't actually copy it.

What is the correct way to copy a range of cells in vb.NET?

Here is the part of my code where the error occurs:

```
                excelApp = New Excel.Application
                excelWB = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(SurveyFormLoc)
                excelApp.Visible = True
                With excelApp

                    .Sheets("Site Details").Select

                    .Range("B2:I11").Copy()

                End With

                excelWB.Save()

                wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
                wdApp.Visible = False
                wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(DesignReportLoc)

                With wdDoc

                    .Application.Selection.Find.Text = "INSERT FROM SURVEY FORM"        
                    .Application.Selection.Find.Execute()
                    .Application.Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 0

                End With

                With wdApp

                    .Selection.PasteSpecial(Link:=True, DataType:=0, Placement:=0, DisplayAsIcon:=False) 'Asked question to get this 
                    .Selection.TypeParagraph()

                End With
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could the problem be that `excelWB.Save()` resets copy selection? The same thing happens in user interface too.